How can add drop-down from other table in my kendo grid
So I want to drop-down of the items that are present in other table and I want them in my kendo grid using asp.net Mvc so how can I do that ?
I tried to take 2 columns name in my main model from the other model that binds the other table for the drop down

Hows your existing code looks like, it would be great if you could include few reproducible sample.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
